# Adapt navigational property using Mapster

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, mapster

I have a `Post` class with a `User` property in it. When I try to get all Posts, I also want to map the `User` to a `UserDto` object.

```
public class Post {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
    public User User {get; set;}
}


var result = await _ctx.Posts.Include(u => u.User.Adapt<UserDto>()).ToListAsync()
```

Adapting inside the `Include` is throwing this error:

> Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are mixing up `Include` because `Entity Framework` and `Mapster` both have that function. The `Include` that you showed us belongs to `Entity Framework` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading

So, first you need to retrieve data with using `Include` as follows:

```
var result = await _ctx.Posts.Include(u => u.User).ToListAsync();
```

On the other hand you need to set mapster config:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<Post, PostDto>.NewConfig()
    .PreserveReference(true);

TypeAdapterConfig<User, UserDto>.NewConfig()
    .PreserveReference(true);
```

See for nested mapping in Mapster:

https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Config-for-nested-mapping

Thus you can get `PostDto` which includes `UserDto`:

```
var postDto = result.Adapt<PostDto>();
```

Comment: Seems to work fine without the mapster config, as long as the Dto property name matches the source object name. Is this expected?